# SELECT row(s) from a table where value does not exist within a group of related records

Tags: sql-server

Apologies for not supplying any SQL, my SQL skills are basic and I've not come across this kind of requirement before.

With a table like the one below:

**Table**

```
id    size   batch code   product code
---------------------------------------
1       91      55555       BigD Red
2       94      55555       BigD Red
3       91      44444       BigD Blue
4       92      44444       BigD Blue
5       93      44444       BigD Blue
6       94      44444       BigD Blue
7       91      33333       BigD Orange
8       94      33333       BigD Orange
```

How to construct an SQL statement which returns the following results?

**Result**

```
id    size   batch code   product code
--------------------------------------
1       91      55555       BigD Red
7       91      33333       BigD Orange
```

Records are grouped by product code. Within each group, I'm looking for only those groups that do **NOT** contain a size of '92'... and wish to display a single record with size '91' from each of those groups. Size 91 always exists in each group.

Comment: SQL-Server or mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic version using `not exists`:

```
select *
from yourtable y1
where size = 91 and not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable y2
    where y1.productcode = y2.productcode and y2.size = 92)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/520929/1)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! My rep is too low for voting but kudos also for supplying SQL Fiddle Demo.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `NOT EXISTS` on `NOT IN`

```
select * 
  from myTable t
 where t.size=91
   and not exists (select 1 from myTable t1 
                    where t1.productCode=t2.productCode
                      and t1.size=92)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MySql, but this will work with Sql server:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Size, T1.BatchCode, T1.ProductCode
FROM Table T1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ProductCode
    FROM Table 
    WHERE Size = 92
) T2 ON T1.ProductCode = T2.ProductCode 
WHERE T1.Size = 91
AND T2.ProductCode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from myTable t
Where id =
   (Select Min(id) from myTable   -- < need this to ensure only one 
    where product code = t.product code
        and size = 91 
        and not exists 
           (Select * from myTable
            Where product code = t.product code
               and size = 92))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from myTable where size!=92
group by productcode having size=91
```

Comment: This one will give only one from each group